# Kibana startup fails with License information and later with Unable to retrieve version information

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, centos, kibana

I'm tried to follow this [guideline](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-elk-stack-centos-8) for installing `ELK` on Centos 8 (on top of one AWS cluster).

After installing `elastic` and `kibana`, the `kibana` startup failed with:

```
*"message":"License information could not be obtained from Elasticsearch
```

I googled it, and realized I should use OSS version (latest is 7.10.2)
so make sure to install only OSS version. you can use this [guideline](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/how-to-install-elk-stack-on-rhel-8.html)

after that, I got new error from `kibana.log`

```
-08T07:19:32Z","tags":["error","savedobjects-service"],"pid":62767,"message":"Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes."}
```

I tried to google it, but no solution worked for me.

my `kibana.yaml`:

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
elasticsearch.hosts: "[my public AWS instance ip:9200]"
```

my `elasticsearch.yaml`:

```
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
discovery.seed_hosts: "[my private AWS instance ip]"
cluster.initial_master_nodes: "[my private AWS instance ip]"
```

**Update:**

If I'm changing this line in `kibana.yaml` file to:

```
elasticsearch.hosts: "http://localhost:9200"
```

Then it works. what is the root cause? why it can't access elastic public IP but only local?

Comment: This error means that your elasticsearch is not running or Kibana can't connect to it. What are your `elasticsearch.yml` and `kibana.yml` file? Update your question with those files.

Comment: I added the yamls data. elasticsearch is running as I'm able to get response from curl

Comment: Are Kibana and Elasticsearch in the same ec2 instance or in different instances? If they are in the same instance, use the private IP and see if it works, if they are in different instances, can you curl elasticsearch from the kibana instance using the public IP? Since your Elasticsearch is running, it seems to be a network issue. Also, Kibana and Elasticsearch needs to be on the same version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per @leandrojmp comment, the issue was indeed with the public IP in `elasticsearch.hosts`. Once I replaced it to my private ip, it works

Answer (score 1):

also:

When installing the Elastic Stack, you must use the same version across the entire stack. For example, if you are using Elasticsearch 7.9.3, you install Beats 7.9.3, APM Server 7.9.3, Elasticsearch Hadoop 7.9.3, Kibana 7.9.3, and Logstash 7.9.3.

Answer (score 1):

Using docker, I had to specify the `elasticsearch.hosts` as an environment variable: `-e "ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://localhost:9200"`, so:

```
docker run -p 5601:5601 -e "ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://localhost:9200" arm64v8/kibana:7.16.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Set elasticsearch.hosts ipaddress as local system's host ipaddress in kibana.yml file. Also you need to mount local kibana.yml file while running docker container.

```
docker run -d --name kibana -p 5601:5601 -v /home/users/mySystemUserName/config/kibana.yml:/opt/kibana/config/kibana.yml kibana:7.16.3
```

Add the below configs in

kibana.yml

```
server.name: kibana
server.port: 5601
server.host: "0.0.0.0"
elasticsearch.hosts: [ "http://192.168.0.102:9200" ]
```