# Running ELK on docker, Kibana says: Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, elastic-stack, elk

I was referring to [example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-get-started/current/get-started-stack-docker.html#get-started-docker-tls) given in the elasticsearch documentation for starting elastic stack (elastic and kibana) on docker using docker compose. It gives example of docker compose version 2.2 file. So, I tried to convert it to docker compose version 3.8 file. Also, it creates three elastic nodes and has security enabled. I want to keep it minimal to start with. So I tried to turn off security and also reduce the number of elastic nodes to 2. This is how my current compose file looks like:

```
version: "3.8"

services:  
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.0.0-amd64
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1g 
    
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      # [
      #   "CMD-SHELL",
      #   # "curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://localhost:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'",
      # ]

      # Changed to:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://localhost:9200 || exit 1"]

      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120
  kibana:
    depends_on:
      - es01
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.0.0-amd64
    volumes:
      - kibanadata:/usr/share/kibana/data
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      - SERVERNAME=kibana
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=https://localhost:9200
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1g
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s -I http://localhost:5601 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120
volumes:
  esdata01:
    driver: local
  kibanadata:
    driver: local
```

Then, I tried to run it:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.nosec.noenv.yml elk
Creating network elk_default
Creating service elk_es01
Creating service elk_kibana
```

When I tried to check their status, it displayed following:

```
$ docker container list
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                       COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                            PORTS                NAMES
3dcd08134e38   docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.0.0-amd64                 "/bin/tini -- /usr/l…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes (health: starting)   5601/tcp             elk_kibana.1.ng8aspz9krfnejfpsnqzl2sci
7b548a43c45c   docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.0.0-amd64   "/bin/tini -- /usr/l…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes (healthy)            9200/tcp, 9300/tcp   elk_es01.1.d9a107j6wkz42shti3n6kpfmx
```

I noticed that kibana's status gets stuck at `(health: starting)`. When I checked Kibana's logs with command `docker service logs -f elk_kibana`, it had following `WARN` and `ERROR` lines:

```
[WARN ][plugins.security.config] Generating a random key for xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.security.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.
[WARN ][plugins.security.config] Session cookies will be transmitted over insecure connections. This is not recommended.
[WARN ][plugins.security.config] Generating a random key for xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.security.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.
[WARN ][plugins.security.config] Session cookies will be transmitted over insecure connections. This is not recommended.
[WARN ][plugins.reporting.config] Generating a random key for xpack.reporting.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.reporting.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.
[WARN ][plugins.reporting.config] Found 'server.host: "0.0.0.0"' in Kibana configuration. Reporting is not able to use this as the Kibana server hostname. To enable PNG/PDF Reporting to work, 'xpack.reporting.kibanaServer.hostname: localhost' is automatically set in the configuration. You can prevent this message by adding 'xpack.reporting.kibanaServer.hostname: localhost' in kibana.yml.
[ERROR][elasticsearch-service] Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9200
```

It seems that kibana is not able to connect with Elasticsearch, but why? Is it because of disabling of security and that we cannot have security disabled?

**PS-1:** Earlier, when I set elasticsearch host as follows in kibana's environment in the docker compose file:

```
ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=https://es01:9200  # that is 'es01' instead of `localhost`
```

it gave me following error:

```
[ERROR][elasticsearch-service] Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND es01
```

So, after checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66994227/kibana-startup-fails-with-license-information-and-later-with-unable-to-retrieve) question, I changed `es01` to `localhost` as specified earlier (that is in complete docker compose file content before PS-1.)

**PS-2:** Replacing `localhost` with `192.168.0.104` gives following error

```
[ERROR][elasticsearch-service] Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.0.104:9200
[ERROR][elasticsearch-service] Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. write EPROTO 140274197346240:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://es01:9200
```

I don't know why it can run in my PC, since Elasticsearch is supossed use SSL. But in your case using `http` working just fine.

Comment: I spent whole day yesterday, but couldn't figure it out!!! **Q1.** Can you tell if there is any webpage in official docs which points to such minimal examples? Next I want to try out metricbeat to monitor existing app running on docker. But I couldnt find any sample docker-compose file in official documentation elaborating the same. **Q2.** Isnt it obvious for `http` to work given that SSL is possibly turned off due to `xpack.security.enabled=false` configuration in docker-compose file?

Comment: 1. I think your reference is already sufficient. I use your reference. You just need add service for metric beat. I don't know if you already see this [link](https://github.com/ypereirareis/docker-metricbeat-example/blob/master/docker-compose.yml).
2. yes, you are right. didn't see that